# Why can't I access my hardcore permanent skill in Kingdom of Loathing?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

It's my third ascension, and after my last ascension I made the skill "tongue of the walrus" hardcore permanent. Now I'm playing a hardcore Avatar of Boris run, but I still can't use Tongue of the Walrus.

Why is this? What do I need to do to access my hardcore permanent skill?

Comment: good to see KoL still going strong.  Meat should seriously be the defacto currency in every game ever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that this is unique to the Avatar of Boris. The only skills that you have access to are the ones that you have obtained while doing the Avatar run.

http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Avatar_of_Boris
(see the the "Skills" section under "Restrictions")